# Application-defined or object-defined error (1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which allows users to enter information onto a single page then press a button to send all the info to where it needs to go. I have a function which checks to see if a sheet exists and then creates a copy of a template sheet and renames it to the required name.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 10
        OpName = Cells(i + 3, 2).Value
        If Not OpName = "" Then
            OpCheck (OpName)
```

So the code above cycles through the cells down row B and runs the opcheck function as described above.

```
Function OpCheck(Init As String)
    Init = UCase(Init)
    exists = False
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = Init Then
            exists = True
        End If
    Next i
    If Not exists Then
        Sheets("Op Template").Visible = True
        Sheets("Op Template").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = Init
        RenameTable (Init)

        On Error Resume Next

    End If
    Sheets("Op Template").Visible = False

End Function
```

This is the code for the function and the error occurs in the line

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Init
```

This has worked some of the time but is now failing to find a sheet with the name TS and gets an error when it tries to rename a new page with a name that already exists. I just don't understand why it isn't finding the page in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really should qualify the workbook the worksheets are in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is sometimes failing to find is because you need to exit the `For` loop once the sheet is found. A fix is:

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(i).Name = Init Then
        exists = True
        Exit For    ' ADD THIS LINE
    End If
Next i
```

A couple of other code comments:

- Consider changing `Function OpCheck` to `Sub OpCheck` since you're not returning anything
- Your code may be causing `Init` to be converted to upper case in the function or sub that calls `OpCheck`. To avoid this, change the declaration to: `OpCheck(ByVal Init As String)`

This section of code:

```
Sheets("Op Template").Visible = True
Sheets("Op Template").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Init
RenameTable (Init)
```

can be made less risky by avoiding `ActiveSheet`

```
dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Op Template")
ws.Visible = True
ws.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

' Instead of this
' ActiveSheet.Name = Init
' Something like this
Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Init
RenameTable (Init)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `Exit For` is a good recommendation as well - but even if the loop continues, `exists` will still be `True`. Perhaps add a point about qualifying the workbook too?

Comment: @BigBen  Yeah I messed that up.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, turns out the problem was a typo on a variable called in the main function.